# How to download an image on device from a direct URL using PHP?

Tags: php

This might seem a repeated question, but trust me I have read many topics here, none of the solutions worked for me

What I particularly aim to do is, let's say I have this image URL - https://catfriendly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/AdobeStock_53119595.jpeg, and I want to Download it on my user's phone. I would redirect the user to URL when he/she clicks the download button, and then the URL's image would be downloaded on the user's phone. Is this possible to do?

I've tried this code,

```
<?php>
$url = 'https://catfriendly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/AdobeStock_53119595.jpeg';
$img = '/Downloads/one.jpeg';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
?>
```

What's wrong in this one? Thanks!

Comment: So, according to your introductory sentence, you have found similar questions but the solutions there didn't work for you? What questions were those? In what way didn't they work? In what way does your code fail? Please, start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, make sure you provide a [mcve], though your code looks very much like one already.

Comment: The above code downloads and stores the file to the server, not "on the user's phone" (or any other client). You're also trying to store the file in a folder called "Downloads" in the root of the file system. Does that folder exist?

Comment: Beside the suggestions Ulrich made before, keep in mind, that PHP is a server side programming language. Your code works perfect, when you respect this fact. You get the contents of the given file and store it in a new file in the given directory on the server and not locally. Think about a download instead of saving the contents on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem with your code is that it is executed on your server, but not on the user's phone.

So you have to modify your code a little:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://catfriendly.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/AdobeStock_53119595.jpeg';

// leave this out because it only stores the image on the server
// $img = '/Downloads/one.jpeg';
// file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));

// get the image content:
$img_content = file_get_contents($url);

// tell the client that you will send an image
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// tell the client not to display the image, but to download it
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="YourFilenameHere.jpg"');

// finally, output the image
echo $img_content;

?>
```